# Create a sparse diagonal matrix from row of a sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I process rather large matrices in Python/Scipy. I need to extract rows from large matrix (which is loaded to coo_matrix) and use them as diagonal elements. Currently I do that in the following fashion:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def computation(A):
  for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    diag_elems = np.array(A[i,:].todense())
    ith_diag = sparse.spdiags(diag_elems,0,A.shape[1],A.shape[1], format = "csc")
    #...

#create some random matrix
A = (sparse.rand(1000,100000,0.02,format="csc")*5).astype(np.ubyte)
#get timings
profile.run('computation(A)')
```

What I see from the `profile` output is that most of the time is consumed by `get_csr_submatrix` function while extracting `diag_elems`. That makes me think that I use either inefficient sparse representation of initial data or wrong way of extracting row from a sparse matrix. Can you suggest a better way to extract a row from a sparse matrix and represent it in a diagonal form?

EDIT

The following variant removes bottleneck from the row extraction (notice that simple changing `'csc'` to `csr` is not sufficient, `A[i,:]` must be replaced with `A.getrow(i)` as well). However the main question is how to omit the materialization (`.todense()`) and create the diagonal matrix from the sparse representation of the row.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def computation(A):
  for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    diag_elems = np.array(A.getrow(i).todense())
    ith_diag = sparse.spdiags(diag_elems,0,A.shape[1],A.shape[1], format = "csc")
    #...

#create some random matrix
A = (sparse.rand(1000,100000,0.02,format="csr")*5).astype(np.ubyte)
#get timings
profile.run('computation(A)')
```

If I create DIAgonal matrix from 1-row CSR matrix directly, as follows:

```
diag_elems = A.getrow(i)
ith_diag = sparse.spdiags(diag_elems,0,A.shape[1],A.shape[1])
```

then I can neither specify `format="csc"` argument, nor convert `ith_diags` to CSC format:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/profile.py", line 70, in run
    prof = prof.run(statement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/profile.py", line 456, in run
    return self.runctx(cmd, dict, dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/profile.py", line 462, in runctx
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in computation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 56, in spdiags
    return dia_matrix((data, diags), shape=(m,n)).asformat(format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 211, in asformat
    return getattr(self,'to' + format)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/dia.py", line 173, in tocsc
    return self.tocoo().tocsc()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 263, in tocsc
    data    = np.empty(self.nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.py", line 47, in upcast
    raise TypeError,'no supported conversion for types: %s' % args
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: object`
```

Comment: did you try `format="csr"` instead?

Comment: With 'csr' for initial data and `A[i,:]` replaced with `A.getrow(i)` I achieved significant speedup. But what I am looking for is to omit materializing the row begore creation of the diagonal matrix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
def computation(A):
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        idx_begin = A.indptr[i]
        idx_end = A.indptr[i+1]
        row_nnz = idx_end - idx_begin
        diag_elems = A.data[idx_begin:idx_end]
        diag_indices = A.indices[idx_begin:idx_end]
        ith_diag = sparse.csc_matrix((diag_elems, (diag_indices, diag_indices)),shape=(A.shape[1], A.shape[1]))
        ith_diag.eliminate_zeros()
```

Python profiler said 1.464 seconds versus 5.574 seconds before. It takes advantage of the underlying dense arrays (indptr, indices, data) that define sparse matrices. Here's my crash course: A.indptr[i]:A.indptr[i+1] defines which elements in the dense arrays correspond to the non-zero values in row i. A.data is a dense 1d array of non-zero the values of A and A.indptr is the column where those values go.

I would do some more testing to make very certain this does the same thing as before. I only checked a few cases.